# Click JS button with VBA when the button has no name/ID

Tags: javascript, vba, excel, internet-explorer

I can't for the life of me figure out how to click the button below with VBA. Any help would be appreciated. I've been able to populate the username/password fields since they have a name so I use getElementsByName but the button doesn't have a name or ID.

The specific button code is:

```
<table class="button"><tr><td><div class="button-left"><input type="submit"  class="form-button"  value="Submit"  >
```

Here is the full script/form code in case it helps

```
<form name="loginFormBean" method="post" action="/XXXXXXXX/login.do" onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">
    <TABLE border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
        <TR>
            <TD class="bigGreyContent" nowrap>User ID</TD>
            <TD class="bigGreyContent" align="left">
                <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="50" size="40" value="" class="bgGreenColor">
            </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD class="bigGreyContent" nowrap>Password</TD>
            <TD class="bigGreyContent" align="left">
                <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="50" size="40" value="" class="bgGreenColor">
            </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD colspan="2" align="center">
            <BR>
            <table class="button"><tr><td><div class="button-left"><input type="submit"  class="form-button"  value="Submit"  ></div><div class="button-right"></div></td></tr></table>     
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
</form>
```

EDIT: I have the following references enabled (in addition to the default ones):

Microsoft HTML Object Library
Microsoft Internet Controls
Microsoft WinHTTP Services, Version 5.1
Microsoft XML, v6.0

My current code is:

```
Sub XXXX()

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim btn As Object
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    Set btn = html.getElementsByClassName("button-left")(0).getElementsByTagName("input")(0)
    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.navigate "http://XXXX/login.jsp"
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    objIE.document.getElementsByName("username")(0).Value = "XXXX"
    objIE.document.getElementsByName("password")(0).Value = "YYYY"
    btn.Click

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming class="button-left" is the first occurrence within your html, try this:

```
Dim btn As Object
Set btn = html.getElementsByClassName("button-left")(0).getElementsByTagName("input")(0)
btn.Click
```

**Edit:**

You should add `Microsoft HTML Object Library` and `Microsoft XML v6.0` if you haven't already, from `Tools -> References`.

Currently you are stuck between your method and my method. You need to pick one so please try this:

```
Sub XXXX()
Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim btn, usr, psw As Object

With CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "http://XXXX/login.jsp", False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

Set usr = html.getElementsByTagName("Form")(0).getElementsByTagName("input")(0)
Set psw = html.getElementsByTagName("Form")(0).getElementsByTagName("input")(1)
Set btn = html.getElementsByTagName("Form")(0).getElementsByTagName("input")(2)

usr.Value = "Username"
psw.Value = "Password"
btn.click

Set html = Nothing: Set btn = Nothing: Set usr = Nothing: Set psw = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I'm getting a 424/Object Required error on the line beginning with 'Set btn', any thoughts? From what I can tell, this IS the first instance of button-left.

Comment: Make sure you have the following in your code: `Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60` `Dim html As New HTMLDocument` `Dim btn As Object`. If it still doesn't work, please share your code, so I can stop guessing what the problem is.

Comment: I've added the code and other info above. Now that I added the two additional Dim's you provided, I get a 91 / Object variable or with block variable not set error, on the same line as before.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost corect.You need to set `Set html = objIE.document` and then change the position of `Set btn = html.getElementsByClassName(...)` so it is after the document has been loaded. Btw. the answer from @Tehscript works as well.

```
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim btn As Object
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

objIE.Visible = True
objIE.navigate Path
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
Set html = objIE.document ' <-- This is the cause of the error 91
Set btn = html.getElementsByClassName("button-left")(0).getElementsByTagName("input")(0) ' <-- Button can be set after the document has been loaded
objIE.document.getElementsByName("username")(0).Value = "XXXX"
objIE.document.getElementsByName("password")(0).Value = "YYYY"
btn.Click
```