# How to speed up VBA web scraper by using MSXML2.XMLHTTP instead of InternetExplorer.Application

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, msxml2

I've just started learning VBA a couple of weeks ago so i apologise if my work has any obvious errors. I've written some code that successfully scrapes data from tables on a website, the problem is that it runs very slowly. I am aware that using internetexplorer.application is quite a slow way to scrape websites and that a quicker way is to use MSXML2.XMLHTTP.

So i'm trying to convert my current code to use MSXML2.XMLHTTP instead of internetexplorer.application but i seem to be making a mess of it. I've searched through quite a lot of questions but i seem to be having issues using things like .getElementsByTagName.

Here's my internetexplorer.application code that i want to convert to MSXML2.XMLHTTP

```
Sub macro6()

Dim internet As InternetExplorer

Dim internetdata As HTMLDocument

Dim internetlink As Object
Dim bbb As Long
Dim internetinnerlink As Object
Dim LR As Long
    LR = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim LR2 As Long
    LR2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Dim LC As Long
    LC = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
Dim y As Long


For bbb = 1 To (LR - 1)
Set internet = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


internet.Visible = False

internet.navigate ("http://data.nowgoal.com/3in1odds/31_" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c1").Offset(bbb, 0)) & ".html"

Do While internet.Busy

  DoEvents

Loop

Do Until internet.READYSTATE = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

  DoEvents

Loop

Set internetdata = internet.document
For y = 2 To 4

hg_blue = internetdata.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(y).getElementsByClassName("hg_blue").Length + 1
hg_red = internetdata.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(y).getElementsByClassName("hg_red").Length
hg_green = internetdata.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(y).getElementsByClassName("hg_green").Length

xx = hg_blue + 1
yy = hg_blue + hg_red
zz = hg_blue + hg_red + hg_green

If zz > 1 Then

    Set internetlink = internetdata.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(y).getElementsByTagName("tr")(xx).getElementsByTagName("td")
    Set internetlink2 = internetdata.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(y).getElementsByTagName("tr")(yy).getElementsByTagName("td")
    Set internetlink3 = internetdata.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(y).getElementsByTagName("tr")(zz).getElementsByTagName("td")


    For Each internetinnerlink In internetlink
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LR2, LC) = internetinnerlink.innerText

    LC = LC + 1
    Next internetinnerlink


    For Each internetinnerlink In internetlink2
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LR2, LC) = internetinnerlink.innerText

    LC = LC + 1
    Next internetinnerlink


    For Each internetinnerlink In internetlink3
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LR2, LC) = internetinnerlink.innerText

    LC = LC + 1
    Next internetinnerlink

Else

    Set internetlink = internetdata.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(y).getElementsByTagName("tr")(1).getElementsByTagName("td")
    Set internetlink2 = internetdata.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(y).getElementsByTagName("tr")(1).getElementsByTagName("td")
    Set internetlink3 = internetdata.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(y).getElementsByTagName("tr")(1).getElementsByTagName("td")


    For Each internetinnerlink In internetlink
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LR2, LC) = ""

    LC = LC + 1
    Next internetinnerlink


    For Each internetinnerlink In internetlink2
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LR2, LC) = ""

    LC = LC + 1
    Next internetinnerlink


    For Each internetinnerlink In internetlink3
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LR2, LC) = ""

    LC = LC + 1
    Next internetinnerlink

End If

Next y
LR2 = LR2 + 1
LC = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LR2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

internet.Quit
Next bbb


End Sub
```

The data in column C are numbers 1274444 in C2, 1274445 in C3, 1274446 in C4 etc.

Is it easier just to start from scratch and write the code again or are there simple changes i can make? Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can have a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43596731/click-js-button-with-vba-when-the-button-has-no-name-id/43597210#43597210) to see the usage of MSXML2.XMLHTTP. You can easily convert your code into MSXML2.XMLHTTP with it.

Comment: Web-scraping with XHR allows to achieve higher performance using no DOM methods, thus it significantly differs from IE automation. Especially for AJAX / DHTML.